# "Your stupid friend is dead. We thought you were dead too" from Bridge To Terabithia?

Tags: story-identification, novel, bridge-to-terabithia

I remember reading a book where a boy comes home to find his family 
crying. His sister (also crying) says "Your stupid friend is dead. We 
thought you were dead too." or something very similar.

I'm almost sure this is [*Bridge to Terabithia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_to_Terabithia_%28novel%29), but can anyone confirm?

Comment: Hey welcome to the Sci-Fi And Fantasy site, sorry to offer this criticism but: The question has a rough title and there is no mention of anything sci-fi or Fantasy related in the question, other than it comes from a children's book that contains some fantasy elements.  The part your asking about though, is just about the main character's experience in the relatively un-fantastical real world that we live in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quote from the book:

> He squinted his eyes as though trying to peer down a dark drain pipe. He didn't even know what question to ask them. "What-?" he tried to begin.  Brenda's pouting voice broke in, "Your girl friend's dead, and Momma thought you was dead, too. "

I'll let you figure out if it's right.

Answer (score 11):

It is *Bridge to Terabithia*, yes.  The actual quote is:

> Brenda's pouting voice broke in, "Your girl friend's dead, and Momma thought you was dead, too."

His family aren't crying when he arrives, but when his mother sees him she lets out "a great shuddering sob", and repeats that over and over.  (His father and other sister are not crying).